# how to install a jar library in liberty web sphere IBM in default server

Tags: java, server, websphere, websphere-liberty

I am trying to install a jar library in the default server in Web Sphere liberty IBM, I already tried putting it in the folder: **..\wlp\lib** but the server doesn't recognize it.
I don´t knoe if I need a xml configuration or some thing like this.

any idea that I may be doing wrong?

the library that i wanna put  in the server is: **com.ibm.ws.webservices.thinclient_8.5.0.jar**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wlp/lib directory is intended for Liberty feature bundles.  If you want to install a JAR file that can be loaded by multiple applications, you will need to create a shared library.  Instructions for creating shared libraries are available here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_classloader.html

It is also possible to install a JAR file that can be loaded without needing to make any configuration changes - this is called the global shared library. To make that work, you would need to copy the JAR file to the wlp/usr/servers//lib/global or wlp/usr/shared/lib/global directories. More info here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_classloader_global_libs.html

There are other ways to add JARs to make them available to applications and/or the Liberty runtime called user features and product extensions, but that probably goes beyond what you are looking for.  If you want more information on these approaches, you can find them here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_feat_develop.html